# How to put closing animation when an item in guillotine menu is clicked?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am using Guillotine menu by yalantis in my app, how can i put a closing animation when i click an item to close the menu.

this is what i've done so far

```
     final View guillotineMenu = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.guillotine, null);
    root.addView(guillotineMenu);
    LinearLayout home = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.home_g);
    home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openHomeFragment();

        }
    });
    LinearLayout news = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.news_g);
    news.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openNewsFragment();

        }
    }); 

new GuillotineAnimation.GuillotineBuilder(guillotineMenu, guillotineMenu.findViewById(R.id.guillotine_hamburger), contentHamburger)
            .setStartDelay(RIPPLE_DURATION)
            .setActionBarViewForAnimation(toolbar)
            .setClosedOnStart(true)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `GuillotineAnimation` with an object.

```
GuillotineAnimation animation = new GuillotineAnimation.GuillotineBuilder(guillotineMenu, guillotineMenu.findViewById(R.id.guillotine_hamburger), contentHamburger)
            .setStartDelay(RIPPLE_DURATION)
            .setActionBarViewForAnimation(toolbar)
            .setClosedOnStart(true)
            .build();

//   Close with animation
        animation.close();
```